# UIview resets to initial position after animation step complete

Tags: ios, swift, animation, catransform3d

I need to rotate clock view with some angle. But second step of animation starting at the initial position, when i need to continue its with the new one.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, options: [.beginFromCurrentState], animations: {

        UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(5)

        self.clock.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi/4), 0, 0, 1)

    }, completion: nil)
```

When i'm trying to do some animation in completion block it doesn't trigger. And after second pressing the button - animation doesn't launching at all, but the console is displaying "true".

```
@IBAction func flip(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

        self.FirstView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi), -1, 1, 0)

    }, completion: { finished in

        print(finished)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {

        self.FirstView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi), -1, 1, 0)
        }, completion: nil)

        })}
```

P.S. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: try to animate view properties not layer.

Comment: @kirander can you give me some examples for 3D rotating with properties?

Comment: In case of 3d you need to use layer animation not UIView. I think, the problem is UIView animation block does not save layer state.